# Paste from list not found in current range to bottom of current range

Tags: excel, vba

I have column A that has all existing categories, new categories are listed in column C. I'm trying to determine how to take these new categories, and add them to column "a" if they aren't already in column A. In the example the new categories in column C are added to column A even if there are already in column A. I would also need range("a1") in the if-then line to be a dynamic range since new categories will be added as the code runs. Some constructive criticism would be greatly appreciated as well to help me in the future.

```
Sub newcategory()


Dim newcatcount As Integer
Dim i As Integer


newcat = Range("c100000").End(xlUp).Row


For i = 1 To newcat


    If Cells(i, 3).Value <> Range("a1") Then
    Cells(i, 3).Select
    Selection.copy
    Range("a100000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    End If

Next




End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  A sample of the data *you have* as well as an example of what you *need it to look like* might help others visualize what you're trying to do.  You can [edit] your question to add screenshot or text as appropriate.  Also, check out "[mcve]", and there are some great tips [here](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Answer (score 0):

Please give this a try...

```
Sub AddNewCategories()
Dim lrA As Long, lrC As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Dim x, y, z(), dict

lrA = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lrC = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

'Array to hold the categories in column A starting from Row1, assuming the categories start from A1. If not, change it accordingly.
x = Range("A1:A" & lrA).Value

'Array to hold the new categories in column C starting from Row1, assuming the categories start from C1. If not, change it accordingly.
y = Range("C1:C" & lrC).Value

Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For i = 1 To UBound(x, 1)
    dict.Item(x(i, 1)) = ""
Next i

For i = 1 To UBound(y, 1)
    If Not dict.exists(y(i, 1)) Then
        dict.Item(y(i, 1)) = ""
        j = j + 1
        ReDim Preserve z(1 To j)
        z(j) = y(i, 1)
    End If
Next i

If j > 0 Then
    Range("A" & lrA + 1).Resize(j).Value = Application.Transpose(z)
End If
Set dict = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use excel built in `RemoveDuplicates()` function, as follows (mind the comments):

```
Option Explicit

Sub newcategory()
    Dim newcat As Range

    With Worksheets("Categories") ' change "Categories" to your actual sheeet name
        Set newcat = .Range("C1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp)) ' get the range of all nwe categories in reference sheet column C from row 1 down to last not empty one
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Resize(newcat.Rows.Count).Value = newcat.Value ' append new categories values below existing categories in column A
        .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlNo ' remove duplicates
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @drestew,, any feedback?